# mysql update and insert statements based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need some help with the mysql statements for inserting and updating rows in a new table based on the contents of another table. I am going to use this in automated perl code, but the mysql statements themselves are what I am having trouble with.

My first table named `PROFILE` looks something like this:

```
+----------+---------------------------+
| ID       | NAME                      |
+----------+---------------------------+
| 0        | Default profile           |
| 04731470 | Development profile       |
| 87645420 | Core Base                 |
| a41401a0 | Core Test                 |
| ba0e3000 | Development profile child |
| e37fe780 | Test2                     |
+----------+---------------------------+
```

The second called `DEPLOYMENT` has these columns (and no rows yet):

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PROF_ID    | char(36)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| NAME       | varchar(60) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ID         | tinyint(4)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

`ID.PROFILE` is the foreign key for `PROF_ID.DEPLOYMENT` and I want all of the values for `ID.PROFILE` to go in `PROF_ID.DEPLOYMENT`. Then I want the `NAME.DEPLOYMENT` and `ID.DEPLOYMENT` fields to be set based on the words found in the `NAME.PROFILE` field.

The following shows what I want to do as far as the insert statements goes, but these failed due to "ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row":

```
INSERT INTO DEPLOYMENT(PROF_ID,NAME,ID) VALUES((select ID from PROFILE where NAME like '%core%'),'Core','2');
INSERT INTO DEPLOYMENT(PROF_ID,NAME,ID) VALUES((select ID from PROFILE where NAME like '%development%'),'Dev','3');
INSERT INTO DEPLOYMENT(PROF_ID,NAME,ID) VALUES((select ID from PROFILE where NAME not like '%development%' and not like '%core%'),'Default','1');
```

I'm not sure where to start on the update part of this but the `ID.DEPLOYMENT` and `NAME.DEPLOYMENT` fields should change as above if the text in the `NAME.PROFILE` fields changes with any of the words above.

This is the resulting `DEVELOPMENT` table I am looking for.

```
+----------+---------------+----+
| PROF_ID  | NAME          | ID |
+----------+---------------+----+
| 0        | Default       | 1  |
| 04731470 | Dev           | 3  |
| 87645420 | Core          | 2  |
| a41401a0 | Core          | 2  |
| ba0e3000 | Dev           | 3  |
| e37fe780 | Default       | 1  |
+----------+---------------+----+
```

Then I want statements to update if any of the `NAME.PROFILE` information changes.

Sorry if this is confusing, I wasn't sure how to explain and I am still learning mysql. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of the `values` keyword, basically:

```
INSERT INTO DEPLOYMENT(PROF_ID,NAME,ID)
    select ID, 'Core','2'
    from PROFILE
    where NAME like '%core%';

INSERT INTO DEPLOYMENT(PROF_ID,NAME,ID) 
    select ID, 'Dev', '3'
    from PROFILE
    where NAME like '%development%';

INSERT INTO DEPLOYMENT(PROF_ID,NAME,ID)
    select ID, 'Default', '1'
    from PROFILE
    where NAME not like '%development%' and not like '%core%';
```

By the way, you could combine these into one statement, using conditional expressions:

```
INSERT INTO DEPLOYMENT(PROF_ID,NAME,ID)
    select ID,
           (case when NAME like '%core%' then 'Core'
                 when NAME like '%development%' then 'Dev'
                 else 'Default'
            end)
           (case when NAME like '%core%' then '2'
                 when NAME like '%development%' then '3'
                 else '1'
            end)
    from PROFILE;
```